# Excel Pivot - Count of distinct values in a given range

Tags: excel, pivot

I've the following data set from which I need the count of distinct values in a pivot. I've tried few function like FREQUENCY, COUNTIFS etc. but I could not make it.

**Input**

> Input Data

[image]

**Output**

> Expected Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an awkward case because the data values are in more than one column and because they are text not numbers.

The only way I could come up with would be to repeat a standard method of getting the distinct values and then use COUNTIF to get the counts.

So starting in F2 I have:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MATCH(0,COUNTIFS($F$1:$F1,$B$2:$B$4),0)),
IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$4,MATCH(0,COUNTIFS($F$1:$F1,$C$2:$C$4),0)),
IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$4,MATCH(0,COUNTIFS($F$1:$F1,$D$2:$D$4),0)),"")))
```

(It's an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>)

And starting in G2:-

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$D$4,F2)
```

[image]

To avoid having to specify an exact range (e.g. $B2:$B4), you could use the following in F2 and adjust it to the maximum number of rows you are likely to use:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(0,IF(ISTEXT($B$2:$B$10),COUNTIFS($F$1:$F1,$B$2:$B$10),1),0)),
IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$10,MATCH(0,IF(ISTEXT($C$2:$C$10),COUNTIFS($F$1:$F1,$C$2:$C$10),1),0)),
IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$10,MATCH(0,IF(ISTEXT($D$2:$D$10),COUNTIFS($F$1:$F1,$D$2:$D$10),1),0)),"")))
```

and this in G2:-

```
=IF(F2="","",COUNTIF($B$2:$D$10,F2))
```

but of course it's restricted to three columns and anything beyond this I think may point to a VBA solution.

There is a also a general formula for distinct values from a 2d array [here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/16/unique-values-from-multiple-columns-using-array-formulas/) but the output includes a zero when blank rows and columns are included so would need some modification.

So here is the modified formula from the reference above  with error handling starting in I2:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(tbl_text, MIN(IF( IF(ISTEXT(tbl_text),COUNTIF($I$1:$I1, tbl_text),1)=0, ROW(tbl_text)-MIN(ROW(tbl_text))+1)),
 MATCH(0, COUNTIF($I$1:$I1, INDEX(tbl_text, MIN(IF(IF(ISTEXT(tbl_text),COUNTIF($I$1:$I1, tbl_text),1)=0, ROW(tbl_text)-MIN(ROW(tbl_text))+1)), , 1)), 0), 1),"")
```

With the counts starting in J2:-

```
=IF(J2="","",COUNTIF(tbl_text,J2))
```

where tbl_text is a named range defined (when I tested it) as $B$2:$E$10

This I think should meet your additional criterion of it being more generalized because you can set tbl_text to include the maximum number of rows and columns that you are likely to use.

Will need a slight further modification to ignore blanks within the table.

Comment: This works perfect with the static content. I'm rather looking for a generalized solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's clear from the question? This would work for three columns and any number of rows, but you could do something different with VBA.

Comment: I will post a version that doesn't need you to specify the exact number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(IF((B2:D4=C10),1,0))
```

To get result after using formula hit `ctrl`+`shift`+`enter`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1COO.jpg]

Comment: This works perfect with the static content. I'm rather looking for a generalized solution.

Comment: please keep active cell in pivot table and hit Alt + F5
then the values will be refreshed 

the same way you can use - Pivot table tools context menu -> Analyze tab -> Data Group and Refresh button. 

if the pivot is connected to any MOSS or DB then change preferences in connection settings :-)